# Home network to accept only certain MAC addresses from LAN

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-10.04

I have Ubuntu 10 as router with WAN(eth0) and LAN(eth1). How can I restric eth1 to accept only packets from certain MAC addresses and drop the rest? I am also about to setup DHCP to certain MAC addresses, however, anyone can manually set IP address. I have like 4-6 my own devices which can use the network.

Comment: FWIW, anyone can manually set MAC addresses, too.

Comment: But they can hardly guess the ones I'm using :)

Comment: All they have to do is sniff...

Comment: sniff wifi? it's not so hostile environment :) Wired network is not accessible. I'm connected through Wifi bridge and need to restrict uninvited guests from wifi.

Comment: Yes, sniff wifi.  It's easier than sniffing wired in that it doesn't require physical access.  The client MAC is sent in the clear even on WPA networks. (You *are* using WPA2, yes?  WEP is... silly.)

Comment: @Insyte Whitelisting wired cards should prevent that, no? Not saying it should be the only layer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I don't think this buys you any real security, or even any more security than blocking based on IP, but something like this should do it:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j ACCEPT
```

Assuming, of course, that your default policy is DROP.

Comment: I'm sorry, the default policy is ACCEPT. Any way?

Comment: Then change it to DROP... then use this command.

Comment: well, how to negate the way that if NOT specified mac, then DROP?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a start for you:

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:BB -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -I INPUT -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:BB -j ACCEPT
```

All mac addresses other than `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` and `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:BB` will not be able to access your router or the internet.

Comment: does it really have to be also in FORWARD table? In which cases it might work?

Answer (score 1):

( I am **user63709**; somehow my Google OpenID login and MyOpenID login got split, when it's actually the same in Stack Overflow)

`arptables` has its own policy. Do **not** confuse it with `iptables`'s policy.

Since you want to "restric [*sic*] eth1 to accept only packets from certain MAC addresses and drop the rest", you will **want** a default DROP policy.

(BTW, I made a slight mistake in the arptables rules above. They should be:)

```
arptables -P IN DROP
arptables -A IN -i eth1 --source-mac <allowed_mac_address> -j ACCEPT
arptables -A IN -i eth1 --source-mac <allowed_mac_address> -j ACCEPT
... and so on ...
```

(Note again, that **`IN`** is a built-in chain *specifically* found only in arptables. Read [arptables' man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/arptables) for more information).

Comment: For some reason it worked during the testing, but didn't work when I put it on startup... no internet connection at all.

Comment: @Michael that's strange... where did you put the arptables commands? the only reason I can think of: the `-P IN DROP` works, but the `-A IN -i eth1` rules failed because the arptables commands got called before eth1 is fully up. try placing the commands in `/etc/rc.local`. don't forget to put in the full path to arptables (`/sbin/arptables` IIRC)

Comment: I put it the same place (above) iptables init, in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown`. Again, it works when I just run the script from shell. I tried also `rc.local`. Anyway, I've used iptables for that as mentioned here. Will upvote your answer as well, as it was useful to know! Thx

Comment: @Michael hmmmm... really strange... another thing I can think of is the difference of the shell used by the startup scripts (`sh` instead of `bash`). you're not using bash-specific syntax, are you?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in **`arptables`**.

It's kind of iptables, but specifically for layer 2. Although it can also 'peek' into some L3 information.

```
arptables -P IN DROP
arptables -A IN --source-hw <allowed_mac_address> -j ACCEPT
arptables -A IN --source-hw <allowed_mac_address> -j ACCEPT
... and so on ...
```

Whenever there's a new MAC Address you want to allow, just do `arptables -A IN --source-hw <address> -j ACCEPT`. The DROP policy ensures other addresses will be, uh, dropped.

Comment: how to negate mac address if default policy is ACCEPT?

Answer (score 0):

Michael, you can not specify more than one mac source per rule so you will need a set of rules like the following (if you are going to use iptables)

```
#Rules for allowing your mac addresses
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:11 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:22 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:33 -j ACCEPT
#One final rule to drop all packets which do not match one of the rules above (are not from one of your allowed macs)
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j DROP
```

Note that these are in the FORWARD chain and **not** the INPUT chain. By having these rules in the FORWARD chain your linux router will not let any mac except your allowed ones to send or receive any traffic through the router. They will still be able to communicate with machines on the same subnet as their own (because that doesn't require them to pass through the router).

You can also control who can connect to your router by duplicating the above rules for the input chain.

```
#Rules for allowing your mac addresses
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:11 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:22 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:33 -j ACCEPT
#One final rule to drop all packets which do not match one of the rules above (are not from one of your allowed macs)
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j DROP
```

Reading your comment on one of the other shorter answers about which cases FORWARD and INPUT work with, here is a short explanation.

**FORWARD** only applies to packets going *through* your router to other subnets or to the outside world (through the WAN) interface. **INPUT** applies to packets which are destined to terminate on the router itself (eg. SSH connections to the router/linux box itself).